# command as parameter itself

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I'm writing a simple Basic-like language. For some reason I want to avoid 'call' keyword so instead of calling subroutine as 'call my_subroutine' I use simply 'my_subroutine'.
*`E.g: a=8:do_something:b=c+d`*

I have a well working method to declare subroutines. Flex is also ok, it recognises when a declared subroutine appears in the user string. However I have difficulties in Bison declaration. I do as follows:

*`%token CALLSUB ... ... ...
stmt:
...
CALLSUB { $$ = opr(CALLSUB, 2, NULL, NULL); }        //note: to be referred later
...`*

My Flex recognises any subroutine and returns as

*`yylval.iValue = ...    //the proper address
return CALLSUB;`*

Up to now it seems ok, but no parameter is returned because there is no parameter declared in Bison (see note above).

At the first glance one may think it could be declared as variable instead of token, but it would led to unexpected horror...

What's the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean when you say "parameter"? Do you mean "semantic value", as in "Semantic value of the CALLSUB token"?

If so, declare `CALLSUB` to have a type (`%token <iValue> CALLSUB`) and use that value in your `bison` action, where it will be `$1`.